# Copy Formatted Text To Clipboard in word-vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to copy all the text in my word doc !!without losing the format! some text is bold, underlined and so on. This is the code i have so far but it just copies plain text.

```
Sub CopyTextToClipboard()
    Dim obj As New DataObject
    Dim mainData As String
    mainData = ActiveDocument.Content.Text
    obj.SetText mainData
    obj.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the `Copy` method.

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveDocument.Content.Text` is just a string containing the unformatted text of the document.

`ActiveDocument.Content.Copy` is the only code you need for copying the document. Depending on where you are copying it to you may also need to ensure that you use the correct paste command to get the original formatting.